# dupal form: how to assign specific id to radio button using form api

Tags: views, forms, theming

I wanted to change id of radio button. But i dont know which attribute shall i use to do that.

```
$form['entry.497535900'] = array(
'#type' => 'radios',
'#title' => t('Category'),
'#options' => array('P' =>'Product','S' => 'Services','O' =>'Others'),
```

);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to assign IDs to each radio option, then you can use custom theme function, to theme your radios. See example:

```
$form['entry.497535900'] = array(
  '#type' => 'radios',
  '#title' => t('Category'),
  '#options' => array('P' =>'Product','S' => 'Services','O' =>'Others'),
  '#theme' => 'mymodule_custom_radios',  
);
```

The #theme parameter specifies function, which overrides the default radios styling function. You will need to define this function in [hook_theme()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_theme/7) and create the content of the function, where you can specify, how radios should be rendered.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_theme.
 */
function mymodule_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
  return array(
    'mymodule_custom_radios' => array(
      'arguments' => array('element' => NULL),
    ),
  );
}
```

Then create the content of this function.

```
function theme_mymodule_custom_radios($element) {
  // You can access all radios options like this - $element['#options'];

  $output = '';
  // ... create html output according to your needs
  return $output;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
'#attributes' => array(
    'id' => 'your-id',
 ),
```

You need use "#attributes".

Comment: but for each radio buttion how can set id.

Comment: for every radio button its cumming same..i want different different id for each radio button..plz help if know about this or any resource will be very helpful

Comment: what is the need to set id for each items?

Comment: i am sending data to google form..and google cheking id to fetch specific radio button data.